# How to do a deep or shallow copy depending on reference modifier?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I have class A, with internal pointers.  I declare variables:

A a;

A b;

A& c;

I would like "a = b" (or "b = a") to do a deep copy, but I would like "c = a" (or "c = b") to act as a reference and reflect changes made to a or b in the future.

I would have thought the the shallow copy/reference behavior for c was automatic, but I think I may have overloaded my assignment operator poorly because it gets called when I say "c = a"and still does a deep copy.

Existing assignment operator signature is: A& operator =( const A& a);

How do I have an overloaded assignment operator for deep copying, but maintain reference like behavior for references?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. References in C++ are not like references in other programming languages that you are clearly used to, since C++ defaults to value semantics not reference semantics. An assignment `a = b` does not automatically make `a` refer to `b` in C++ - it causes the value of `b` to be copied into the object `a` - using the assignment operator. If `a` is a reference, then `b` is copied into the object referred to by `a`.  If `b` is a reference, then the value of object it refers to is copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ wants a reference to act like just another name for the object to which the reference was bound. It *specifically* does not want users to be able to rebind references, to make a bound reference refer to a different object.

As such, if `c` is a reference to `a`, then every use of `c` will behave exactly as if you used `a` (with some minor exceptions, none of which are applicable for your uses). You cannot "maintain reference like behavior for references;" that's simply not what the language feature is for.

What you want is a pointer (or `std::reference_wrapper`, but pointers are generally what you want). That way, you can make the distinction between a rebind operation (`c = &a`) and a value assignment operation (`*c = a`).

Comment: @ChadMourning: No, it's not a shame; [it's a well-designed feature](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380609/from-a-language-design-perspective-is-the-reference-type-in-c-mis-designed/380636#380636).

Answer (score 4):

This is not how references work in c++. A reference is bound to another variable only at the time of declaration. In fact, this code

```
A& c;
```

will not even compile. You *must* bind it to some other variable, like this:

```
A& c = a;  // does not call operator= (no deep copy)
```

After this point however, assigning to `c` will call the copy assignment operator if you do `c = b;`, and this will do a deep copy. Note that since `c` is bound to `a`, this is the same as assigning `b` to `a`.

Comment: I think that was true before like C++17, but it was my understanding that I'm pretty sure you can at least punt until construction time if, for instance the reference is a member variable of a class.

But if it only works the way I want the "first tme", I understand, I guess I'll switch to a pointer.

Comment: It's true that members that are references can be bound at construction, but the same logic would apply after that point.

Answer (score 1):

> A& c;

That's not how we define a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) variable in C++. Reference should be 
 bound to an object at the point of their definition. After their creation, they can't be changed to point to something else.

The right way to do it:

```
A&c = a;
```

For the above point, there is no constructor being called. It's just that `c` is made an alias for the object `a`. However, if you do `c = b`, then `copy assignment` for objects `a` and `b` will be called as you can see below.

> I would have thought the the shallow copy/reference behavior for c was automatic, but I think I may have overloaded my assignment operator poorly because it gets called when I say "c = a"and still does a deep copy.

`c = a` calls copy constructor of object `a` and `b`. [Pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) in C++ would be better option for you. They can be changed to point to any object. See my example for pointers in `main` function below and it does the `shallow` copy (see no constructor or assignment operator being called).

An example to show what's being called for which object:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

public:
    A(void)
    {
        std::cout << "__CONSTRUCTOR__" << std::endl;
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A& )
    {
        std::cout << "__COPY_CONSTRUCTOR__" << std::endl;
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    const A& operator=(const A& other)
    {
        std::cout << "__COPY_ASSIGNMENT__" << std::endl;
        std::cout << this << " and " << &other <<  std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~A(void)
    {
        std::cout << "__DESTRUCTOR__" << std::endl;
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Example with reference" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------ CREATING A ------------" << std::endl;
    A a;
    std::cout << "------------ CREATING B ------------" << std::endl;
    A b;
    std::cout << "------------ CREATING C ------------" << std::endl;
    A& c = b;
    std::cout << "-------------- C = A ---------------" << std::endl;
    c = a;


    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Example with pointers" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------ CREATING D ------------" << std::endl;
    A *d;
    std::cout << "-------------- D = &A --------------" << std::endl;
    d = &a;
    std::cout << "-------------- D = &B --------------" << std::endl;
    d = &b;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Leaving the program" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Example with reference
------------ CREATING A ------------
__CONSTRUCTOR__
0x7fffe46d4ed6
------------ CREATING B ------------
__CONSTRUCTOR__
0x7fffe46d4ed7
------------ CREATING C ------------
-------------- C = A ---------------
__COPY_ASSIGNMENT__
0x7fffe46d4ed7 and 0x7fffe46d4ed6


Example with pointers
------------ CREATING D ------------
-------------- D = &A --------------
-------------- D = &B --------------


Leaving the program
__DESTRUCTOR__
0x7fffe46d4ed7
__DESTRUCTOR__
0x7fffe46d4ed6
```